# Why do semi-colons in c++ seem to implicitly handle errors? [tldr: they don't]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, while-loop

This is in the visual studio 2019 community edition distribution of c++ on windows. I have this code below:

```
char c;
c = getc(stdin); // reading in some value
while(c != ';');
{
    // do something
}
```

When the semi-colon was on the end of the while loop it stopped an exception from being thrown. One that seemed to be triggered in the loop, where 'do something' is. When I change it to this:

```
char c;
c = getc(stdin); // reading in some value
while(c != ';')
{
    // do something -> exception thrown
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?
EDIT: Just to be more specific. In the '// do something' part of the loop I was changing the value of c and so forth, I didn't think it was relevant so I didn't include it.

Comment: Note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**, which is very important if you ever want to check for `EOF` (which you *always* should do).

Comment: And if you get an exception, then you probably have some error in the "do something" code you don't show. Perhaps ask a new question about it?

Comment: I believe the compiler removed the expression `while(c != ';');` because it does nothing.

Comment: Lastly, why do you use the C `getc` function in C++ code? Why not use the standard C++ `std::cin` stream? Won't help to solve your problem here or the crash, but it would be "nicer". :)

Comment: To answer the question about why I was using getc. I was having issues with the C++ implementation, and being confident with c,I changed everything so it was setup for how I do it in c and then was slowly changing it as I fix things to c++.

Comment: Infinite loop `while(c != ';');` is UB.

Comment: Compiler can warn about this kind of mistake, if the compiler warnings turned on.

Comment: Yeah, that was the strange thing. I expected it to warn me about that. I get warnings about declaring enums instead of enum classes but not this. I changed it so I get maximum warnings now. You can never have to many, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
while(c != ';');
{
    // Do something
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while(c != ';')
{
    // Empty body
}
{
    // Do something
}
```

So you have a (probably) infinite loop first, *then* the "Do something" code in its own nested scope.

Answer (score 3):

The `// do something` part in the first snippet is **not** part of the `while` loop, *cf.* the second snippet where it is.

That's a sufficient control flow change to change the behaviour of your program.

Answer (score 3):

This statement

```
while(c != ';');
```

can invoke an infinite loop if `c` is not equal to `';'`. The body of the loop is the empty statement `;`. So `c` is not changed.

In this statement

```
while(c != ';')
{
    // do something -> exception thrown
}
```

the body of the loop consists of the compound statement

```
{
    // do something -> exception thrown
}
```

within which for example `c` can be changed or there can be present a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

getc function needs an input stream, like this: getc(input_stream). You can also use the **keyboard** or **file** input stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  char c = ' ';
  while(c != ';') {
    c = getc(stdin);
    printf("%c", c);
    }
  return 0;
}
```